# Can I filter for tags that must all be present? (not just one)

Tags: search, elasticsearch, filtering

Let's say I have a document indexed in elasticsearch with tags: `["red", "blue"]`

And I have a search for tags: `["red"]`

In my current implementation ([terms query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)) I bring back the result, but with a new business rule we want to return only an "all tag" match.

For example, given the document and a search filtered with `tags`:

```
["red"]                    # => no match
["red", "blue", "green"]   # => no match
["red", "blue"]            # => match
["blue", "red"]            # => match
```

Is there a proper filter for this in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use QueryStringQueryBuilder and set default operator to 'AND' (since by default its OR)

Comment: I've tried changing the terms query execution mode to 'AND' and it unfortunately doesn't seem to work.

I think the overall builder may not work since my tags are all within 'tags' at the model level (by the way using Tire and ruby on rails)

Answer (score 0):

**[Script Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html)** (may not be most optimal, but works)

- `fieldName` would be "tag" in this case, the name of the indexed field.
- `searchValues` is my array of terms I want to match completely.

Both passed in as params

```
        all_values_mvel_script = """
fieldValues = doc[fieldName].values;
if (fieldValues.empty) {
    return false;
}
foreach (value : fieldValues) {
    if (!searchValues.contains(value)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
        """
```

The above script is passed as a string to a script type filter. This performs fine in my testing but cannot be cached and is more painful to maintain

Answer (score 0):

use a bool query. Something like this should do the trick.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {"tag":"blue"}
            },
            {
                "term": {"tag":"red"}
            }
        ],
        "should": [],
        "must_not": [
            {
                "term": {"tag":"green"}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You'll have to explicitly exclude everything you don't want to match.

Comment: Thanks do you have a suggestion to make it dynamic? It's a bit too "hard-coded" to my example as is

Comment: I don't see any easy way to do that. In a database, you'd do this with a combination of joins. In elastic search basically you are matching specific, specified terms and your problem is that the full set of terms is not known. You might be able to fake something with a custom score query and simply rank everything with too >2 tags at 0 but you can't express this using simple boolean logic on terms.

Comment: another option that just occurred to me since you are looking to query for exact and specific combinations of tags is to index in a different way: simply sort the tags, concatenate them into a single string, and index them in a non analyzed field. Then you can do an exact match on the full field. A bit of a hack as well but it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for continued thinking on this.  I am not sure a single field string would work for re-ordered terms (see last 2 matching examples in question). Unless there is an implicit ordering that happens?

Comment: You could write an analyzer that orders them consistently (e.g. sorts them).